# 2 characters stop when other jump or 2 stop when changing the Direction - JAVA

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

I'm trying to make 2 players Mario game for my school project but whenever Mario 1 jumping or go first, Mario 2 will stay still and move if i press multiple times.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ATG3h_Om849_HBEaWiEIdADIC-SQ_dF7/view?usp=sharing - My Source if anyone wants to look for more specific details.
this is my KeyBind class and my Main when they receive input

```
package manager;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class KeyBindingManager {
    private GameEngine engine;

    private InputMap inputMap;
    private ActionMap actionMap;

    public KeyBindingManager(GameEngine engine, JFrame frame) {
        this.engine = engine;

        int condition = JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
        this.inputMap = frame.getRootPane().getInputMap(condition);
        this.actionMap = frame.getRootPane().getActionMap();

        init();
    }

    private void init() {

        this.bindKey(KeyEvent.VK_W, "VK_W_Action", () -> {
            GameStatus status = this.engine.getGameStatus();

            if (status == GameStatus.START_SCREEN || status == GameStatus.MAP_SELECTION)
                return ButtonAction.GO_UP;
            else {
                engine.receiveInputMario(ButtonAction.M_JUMP);
                return null;
            }
        });

        this.bindKey(KeyEvent.VK_S, "VK_S_Action", () -> {
            GameStatus status = this.engine.getGameStatus();

            if (status == GameStatus.START_SCREEN || status == GameStatus.MAP_SELECTION)
                return ButtonAction.GO_DOWN;

            return null;
        });

        this.bindKey(KeyEvent.VK_D, "VK_D_Action", () -> {
            engine.receiveInputMario(ButtonAction.M_RIGHT);
            return null;
        });

        this.bindKey(KeyEvent.VK_A, "VK_A_Action", () -> {
            engine.receiveInputMario(ButtonAction.M_LEFT);
            return null;
        });

        this.bindKey(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, "VK_ENTER_Action", () -> {
            return ButtonAction.SELECT;
        });

        this.bindKey(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, "VK_ESCAPE_Action", () -> {
            GameStatus status = this.engine.getGameStatus();

            if (status == GameStatus.RUNNING || status == GameStatus.PAUSED)
                return ButtonAction.PAUSE_RESUME;
            else
                return ButtonAction.GO_TO_START_SCREEN;
        });

        this.bindKey(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, "VK_SPACE_Action", () -> {
            engine.receiveInputMario(ButtonAction.M_FIRE);
            return null;
        });
 
        this.bindKey(KeyEvent.VK_UP, "VK_UP_Action", () -> {
            engine.receiveInputMario2(ButtonAction.M_JUMP);
            return null;
        });

        this.bindKey(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, "VK_RIGHT_Action", () -> {
            engine.receiveInputMario2(ButtonAction.M_RIGHT);
            return null;
        });

        this.bindKey(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, "VK_LEFT_Action", () -> {
            engine.receiveInputMario2(ButtonAction.M_LEFT);
            return null;
        });

        this.bindKey(KeyEvent.VK_0, "VK_P_Action", () -> {
            engine.receiveInputMario2(ButtonAction.M_FIRE);
            return null;
        });
    }

    private void bindKey(int keyEvent, String actionName, Supplier<ButtonAction> action) {
        this.inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyEvent, 0, false), actionName + "_Press");
        this.actionMap.put(actionName + "_Press", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ButtonAction currentAction = ButtonAction.NO_ACTION;

                currentAction = action.get();

                if (currentAction != null) {
                    notifyInput(currentAction);
                }
            };
        });
        this.inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyEvent, 0, true), actionName + "_Release");

        this.actionMap.put(actionName + "_Release", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (keyEvent == KeyEvent.VK_D || keyEvent == KeyEvent.VK_A || keyEvent == KeyEvent.VK_W || keyEvent == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
                    engine.receiveInputMario(ButtonAction.ACTION_COMPLETED);
                }
                if (keyEvent == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || keyEvent == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || keyEvent == KeyEvent.VK_UP || keyEvent == KeyEvent.VK_0 ) {
                    engine.receiveInputMario2(ButtonAction.ACTION_COMPLETED);
                }
            };
        });
        
    }

    private void notifyInput(ButtonAction action) {
        if (action != ButtonAction.NO_ACTION)
            engine.receiveInput(action);
    }

    

    
}
```

```
public void receiveInputMario(ButtonAction input) {
        if (gameStatus != GameStatus.RUNNING)
            return;

        Mario mario = mapManager.getMario("mario");

        if (input == ButtonAction.M_JUMP) {
            mario.jump(this);
        } else if (input == ButtonAction.M_RIGHT) {
            mario.move(true, camera);
        } else if (input == ButtonAction.M_LEFT) {
            mario.move(false, camera);
        } else if (input == ButtonAction.ACTION_COMPLETED) {
            mario.setVelX(0);
        } else if (input == ButtonAction.M_FIRE) {
            mapManager.fire(this);
        }
    }

    public void receiveInputMario2(ButtonAction input) {
        if (gameStatus != GameStatus.RUNNING)
            return;

        Mario mario2 = mapManager.getMario("mario2");

        if (input == ButtonAction.M_JUMP) {
            mario2.jump(this);
        } else if (input == ButtonAction.M_RIGHT) {
            mario2.move(true, camera);
        } else if (input == ButtonAction.M_LEFT) {
            mario2.move(false, camera);
        } else if (input == ButtonAction.ACTION_COMPLETED) {
            mario2.setVelX(0);
        } else if (input == ButtonAction.M_FIRE) {
            mapManager.fire(this);
        }
    }

    public void receiveInput(ButtonAction input) {
        if (gameStatus == GameStatus.START_SCREEN) {
            if (input == ButtonAction.SELECT && startScreenSelection == StartScreenSelection.START_GAME) {
                startGame();
            } else if (input == ButtonAction.SELECT && startScreenSelection == StartScreenSelection.VIEW_ABOUT) {
                setGameStatus(GameStatus.ABOUT_SCREEN);
            } else if (input == ButtonAction.SELECT && startScreenSelection == StartScreenSelection.VIEW_HELP) {
                setGameStatus(GameStatus.HELP_SCREEN);
            } else if (input == ButtonAction.SELECT && startScreenSelection == StartScreenSelection.GAME_SCORE) {
                setGameStatus(GameStatus.GAME_SCORE);
            } else if (input == ButtonAction.GO_UP) {
                selectOption(true);
            } else if (input == ButtonAction.GO_DOWN) {
                selectOption(false);
            }
        } else if (gameStatus == GameStatus.MAP_SELECTION) {
            if (input == ButtonAction.SELECT) {
                selectMapViaKeyboard();
            } else if (input == ButtonAction.GO_UP) {
                changeSelectedMap(true);
            } else if (input == ButtonAction.GO_DOWN) {
                changeSelectedMap(false);
            }
        } else if (gameStatus == GameStatus.RUNNING) {
            if (input == ButtonAction.PAUSE_RESUME) {
                pauseGame();
            }
        } else if (gameStatus == GameStatus.PAUSED) {
            if (input == ButtonAction.PAUSE_RESUME) {
                pauseGame();
            }

        } else if (gameStatus == GameStatus.GAME_OVER && input == ButtonAction.GO_TO_START_SCREEN) {
            reset();
        } else if (gameStatus == GameStatus.MISSION_PASSED && input == ButtonAction.GO_TO_START_SCREEN) {
            reset();
        }

        if (input == ButtonAction.GO_TO_START_SCREEN) {
            setGameStatus(GameStatus.START_SCREEN);
        }
    }
```

I've try using chain of responsibility but it didn't work, i don't know what to do next. Help me please and i really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you more explain "didn't work"?

Comment: Your description of your problem is not clear (at least to me). Can you [edit] your question and post a [mcve]? Rather than post the parts of your code where you think the problem is, post the minimal amount of code that reproduces your problem. Then I can run it myself and debug it.